# Flashed magisk_patched_boot.img as fastboot flash recovery...Phone stuck on Powered by Android

Tags: adb, rooting, fastboot

I was trying to root my Micromax Q440 and I tried to follow the steps ie;

1:  `fastboot flash recovery c:\twrp.img`
2: `fastboot flash boot c:\magisk_patched.img`

but in the 2nd step, I used `recovery` instead of `boot` as a result my phone is currently stuck on "Powered by Android" screen and none of the `Power + Volume(up)` functions are working.

It also shows `Orange State` and your device will `boot in 5 seconds`

Is there a way to recover or this device is gone forever..?

Comment: *orange state* is just a warning that bootloader is unlocked (ignore). magisk has changed usage. before patching *boot.img* select *advanced settings - preserve force encryption* then try again. you can do it on any device. undo at any time by flashing original *boot.img + recovery.img* from fastboot *(Vol-Dn + Power)*